# Error when running Webpack-CLI-bundled file that imports "prettier-plugin-java"

Tags: webpack, prettier, webpack-cli

I am trying to use Webpack to bundle some code that runs the Prettier API to beautify code programmatically.

I have successfully bundled and ran Prettier with one of Prettier's built-in plugins. Using a config of :

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './index.js',
  };
```

I was able to run the resulting `./dist/main.js` file using node.

Now I want to use the `prettier-plugin-java` plugin with Prettier. The problem is that when I `import "prettier-plugin-java"` into my `index.js`, run `npx bundle`, and then try to run the resulting file, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')
    at un (./main.js:1:78927)
    at t.initRecognizerEngine (./main.js:1:95278)
    at new t (./main.js:1:115440)
    at new t.exports (./main.js:1:131052)
    at 602 (./main.js:1:129653)
    at n (./main.js:1:357488)
    at 2507 (./main.js:1:242476)
    at n (./main.js:1:357488)
    at 8402 (./main.js:1:234446)
    at n (./main.js:1:357488)
```

I tried replacing the import statement with `require "prettier-plugin-java"`. Then I was able to run the file without error using node from the terminal.

I expected that I would get the same result (no error) when running my bundled `./dist/main.js` from the terminal. Instead I got the above error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '1')`

Versions I am using:

```
"prettier": "^3.2.5",
"prettier-plugin-java": "^2.5.0",
"webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
```